# strftime syntax while sending command with sshclient_exec_command

Tags: python, linux, strftime

I am getting the current time from system with datetime and storing it as string(timenow), but there is some behaviour difference when i send it to set in linux through sshclient_exec_command.

Below is my code:

```
timenow = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
command = 'date -s %s' %timenow
stdin, stdout, stderr = self._sshclient.exec_command(command, timeout=10)
try:
    command = 'date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'
    stdin, stdout, stderr = self._sshclient.exec_command(command, timeout=10)
    ip_time_now = stdout.read().decode(encoding='UTF-8').rstrip('\n')
    self.logger.debug(" ip=%s timenow=%s ip_time_now=%s",ip, timenow,ip_time_now)
```

Output

```
 timenow=2016-09-07 20:15:26 ip_time_now=2016-09-07 21:06:24
```

Both timenow and ip_time_now are supposed to be same from the operations

Here if I replace the timenow line with

```
timenow = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%H:%M:%S")  #passes, but without 
                                                      setting the year and month
```

Output

```
timenow=20:25:49 ip_time_now=2016-09-07 20:25:50 #1 sec diff is ok
```

Note: There is no exception in the output while executing the commands

What would be possible solution for the strftime syntax?